# Windows 7: dual monitor cuts wallpaper if resolutions are different

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, desktop-customization

I am using two monitors right now, one of them configured to 1920x1080 and the other one to 1366x768 and I am not being able to fit my wallpaper properly to both screens. Windows is resizing the image always to the main monitor and putting it to the second one as it is (with the dimensions of the first).

[This link](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r26139288-Dual-display-cut-off-normal-) has some illustrations. Somebody posted this NVIDIA control panel option but it is unavailable to me.

Would it be a GPU, driver or OS problem?

My GPU is a GeForce GT 520M

Driver version: 9.18.13.2057

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 'tile' mode and create a wallpaper in photoshop/gimp etc which covers both screens, ie add the widths together. As the heights differ too there will be a bit of juggling getting them vertically aligned. One advantage of this approach is that the wallpapers need not be the same.

Comment: Not the ideal solution but it is one at least